# database design - when one record has many properties

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to design a database, but not sure how to handle this situation.

Assume I have a table with geographical locations - hundreds of thousands of them.

Now assume I want to store data for "widgets". In theory, each widget has a "level" that corresponds to each and every geo location - some have a "level" of 0 or NA and the rest have other various values. Each widget also has a "level" for any combination of the hundreds of geo locations.  So for example, if widget A has a level of 10 for Chicago and 20 for New York, it also has a level of 30 for (Chicago+New York). I do not have the ability to store ALL combinations of geo locations for every widget level (ie, I don't have access to ALL of that data).

Instead, I want to store the level for each widget that my users input.  So, the users are able to obtain these level values however they choose (ie, with whatever combination of geo locations they want). They tell me what widget it is, what combination of geo locations they chose, and the value of the level.

How do I store this data?

The answer may be super simple and I may just not be thinking properly, but any assistance would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: So what data are you looking to store after a user interacts with a widget?  Are they going to be able to select a thousand locations?  Are they going to be able to pick a limited number of locations?  How are you using this data after it gets stored?  I mean this gets into database design and best practices so specifics are very important.

I mean are you only concerned with the summed value of the geo locations, the widget ID and the names of the locations concatenated in a field?  Do you need to be able to edit the geo locations later so each widget needs to know each geo_ID of each entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could do something like this:

1. A table of geo locations with PK GeoLocationID
2. A table of users with PK UserID
3. A table of widgets with PK WidgetID
4. A table of user-defined levels for widget-geo location combinations i.e.

   TABLE UserWidgetLocation(

   ```
   UserID PK FK,
   WidgetID PK FK,
   GeoLocationID PK FK,
   Level )
   ```

Comment: yea i think this is the route to go. looking back at my question, i realized the solution was pretty straightforward and this is pretty much what i was thinking too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark to see if I understand what you're asking for.  I mean this is the most basic format where you don't edit any widgets currently in use and just want to store user inputs as sums and concatenated geo names.

For GeoLocation:

```
Geo_ID (INT) | Geo_Name (VARCHAR) | Geo_Value (VARCHAR) | ...Other Info...
```

For Widget:

```
Widget_ID (INT) |  Widget_Name (VARCHAR) | ...Other Info...
```

For WidgetEvent:

```
Event_ID (INT) | Widget_ID (INT) |  Geo_Sum (INT) |  Geo_Names (VARCHAR) | ...Other Info...
```